# Program crashing when compiled with xcode 4.2

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

I tried to run my project in ios 5 simulator then the app crashes with this message
thread 1 program received signal sigabrt
i googled it regarding this problem and followed forums it says to check your interface builder outlets and check whether already released object are not being release so i enable NSZombie, but not able to understand the cause of the crash and unable to resolve
i'll be really thankful if someone could help me with that.
one more important thing it runs fine in ios 4.2 simulator only shows problem in ios 5 simulator
here is the stack trace

Application Specific Information:

iPhone Simulator 272, iPhone OS 5.0 (iPhone/9A334)
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:

0 libSystem.B.dylib 0x962dbc5a __kill + 10

1 libSystem.B.dylib 0x962dbc4c kill$UNIX2003 + 32

2 libSystem.B.dylib 0x9636e5a5 raise + 26

3 libSystem.B.dylib 0x96384679 __abort + 124

4 libSystem.B.dylib 0x963846f5 abort_report_np + 0

5 libSystem.B.dylib 0x96300b1b _Unwind_Resume + 59

6 CoreFoundation 0x0231de39 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 345

7 CoreFoundation 0x0231dccb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123

8 GraphicsServices 0x02c05879 GSEventRunModal + 207

9 GraphicsServices 0x02c0593e GSEventRun + 114

10 UIKit 0x0018ba9b UIApplicationMain + 1175

11 FINS 0x0000296d main + 125 (main.m:14)

12 FINS 0x000028e5 start + 53

Thread 1:

0 libSystem.B.dylib 0x962a1382 kevent + 10

1 libdispatch.dylib 0x02a61373 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 918

2 libdispatch.dylib 0x02a5fcd0 _dispatch_mgr_wakeup + 0

Thread 2: WebThread

0 libSystem.B.dylib 0x9627aafa mach_msg_trap + 10

1 libSystem.B.dylib 0x9627b267 mach_msg + 68

2 CoreFoundation 0x023bb13a __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 186

3 CoreFoundation 0x0231e605 __CFRunLoopRun + 1445

4 CoreFoundation 0x0231ddb4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212

5 CoreFoundation 0x0231dccb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123

6 WebCore 0x03c80220 RunWebThread(void*) + 560

7 libSystem.B.dylib 0x962a8259 _pthread_start + 345

8 libSystem.B.dylib 0x962a80de thread_start + 34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried inserting a breakpoint on the first view that loads? Then debug from there until you find specifically which line it is thats causing the crash.

Comment: yes i debug it and it wasnt crashing in any of the function in first view

Comment: Debug until you hit the crash. Thats my best adwice :-)

Comment: the thing is it is getting crashed at main.m not in any of the view controllers file.